# typeahead not showing any results for second input

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, typeahead.js

I am using Typeahead for two inputs, i got it to work for the first input, but it is not working for the second input, I am not sure what's the issue here and why it is not working, I have changed IDs and everything, but the request is not showing any details at all.

here is my create.blade.php

```
@csrf

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Customer Name:</strong>
          <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="customer_id" id='cust' onkeypress="myFunction()" placeholder="Customer Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Card Number:</strong>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customer_id" id='card' onkeypress="myFunction1()" placeholder="Customer Name">
          </div>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
  var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
  $('#cust').typeahead({
    name: 'cust',
      source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {

              return process(data);
          });
      }
  });
}
function myFunction1()
{

  var path = "{{ route('autocompletecard') }}";
  $('#card').typeahead({
    name: 'card',
      source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
              return process(data);
          });
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
          {
              $data = Customer::select("name")
                      ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                      ->get();

              return response()->json($data);
          }
          public function autocompletecard(Request $request)
              {
                  $data = Card::select("cardno")
                          ->where("cardno","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                          ->get();

                  return response()->json($data);
              }
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('autocompletecard', 'AssigneeController@autocompletecard')->name('autocompletecard');
```

Comment: let's say the error comes from the `html` tags, so let's duplicate it but change only the id, keep the same function then test it.  
so the only difference is the ID of the tag! please post what you got after testing. P.S. we may need many tries to get it to work.

Comment: I am starting to think the error is from the Model it self. because when changing the class from Customer to Card in the controller, I am only getting results returned on the console but not prompted in auto complete

Comment: I have changed the column name from “cardno” to “name” somehow it worked.

Comment: Sounds like something was stepping on the variable.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your browser doesn't like whatever TypeAhead has auto-added for the autocomplete element.  Try manually adding `autocomplete="off"` to your second input.  You can check what TypeAhead has added - look at your source.  It may not work in FF, but may in Chrome.  The browsers are picky on this point.

Can try this:

```
<input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="customer_id" id='card' onkeypress="myFunction1()" placeholder="Customer Name">
```

Alternatively, try with autocomplete="false".  Chrome sometimes balks at 'off'.

Comment: Hi, I have used Safari and Chrome and firefox, same results, could it be the module? the interesting thing is I am getting the value returned in the console.. I can see the value, but it is not being prompted as autocomplete